# how to deploy large sized deep learning model using streamlit?

Tags: deployment, web-applications, streamlit, webapp2

I have saved an (.h5) model with size about 85GB. I am trying to build a webapp using streamlit. However, I face the problem or loading my model, as I can not upload it to github. I tried to shrink the size of the saved model using tensorflow lite, but it only reduced the size to about 80GB. Is there a way to deploy my model for free using streamlit or other tools with my saved model.
The code and the issue is at https://github.com/kenanmorani/COVID-19Deployment.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even when using the Git Large File Storage, you can't use larger files than 5GB with Github. I think the easiest way for you would be to save your model in Gdrive and provide the url to your streamlit application.
An easy way to download public files from gdrive in python is the library [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown).

If the model should remain private, you would need to rely on the google drive api and the usage of streamlits [secrets](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management) to pass the credentials.